# Parametric region cannnot be automatically discretized/not a valid region to plot

Tags: plotting, regions

When I try to plot this simple parametric region:

```
ParametricRegion[{x, Sin[z + t] + Sin[t - z]}, {{x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}}];
RegionPlot[%]
```

I get errors telling me the "parametric region cannot be automatically discretized" and "is not a valid region to plot".

How can I plot this parametric region ?

Comment: Is that an $x$ or a $z$?  If you change $x$ to $z$, you get output.  Also, please add a `]` at the end of the first line.

Comment: @mjw Thanks. Actually, it is an x not a z.

Comment: Please describe in mathematical terms the region you want to plot.  Is it a 2D or 3D region?

Comment: It is a 2D region defined as the set of points of coordinates ( x , sin(t+z)+sin(t-z) ) when x, t and z run over the interval [0,1]

Comment: If it is a 2D region, what are the abscissa and ordinate variables?  It could only be two of these three, right?:  $\{t,x,z\}$

Comment: It is a parametric function depending on 3 parameters (t,x,z) whose abscissa is x and whose ordinate is sin(t+z)+sin(t-z). If I plot the parametric region: ParametricRegion[{x, Sin[z + t]}, {{x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}}]; it works, it is a 2D region and there are 3 parameters runing over [0,1].

Comment: The $x$-axis is $x$.  The $y$-axis is $t$ or $z$?

Comment: Neither of the two. For instance, when you parametrize a circle by a parameter t, you get the parametric curve defined by {x(t),y(t)} for t running over [0,2Pi] where x(t)=cos(t) and y(t)=sin(t). It means the abscissa is x(t) and the ordinate is y(t). t is a parameter, so it is neither the "x-axis" nor the "y-axis".

Comment: Okay, so $x$ depends only on $x$ and $y$ depends both on $z$ and $t$.  Also $x$ and $y$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's not worry about $x$ for now.  For a few values of $z$, we plot the curve representing $y$:

```
 p = 3; Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[z - t] - Sin[z + t], {z, Range[0,p]/p}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

For various values of $z$, we can now plot the regions in $xy$-space.

```
 p = 3; 
 ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@
     Table[{x, Sin[z - t] - Sin[z + t]}, {z, Range[0,p]/p}], {x, 0,1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The union of all of the regions is the region with $z=0$:

```
 ParametricPlot[{x, -2 Sin[t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

This is a rectangle of width 1 and height $2 \sin 1 \approx 1.68294$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your steps but this is not exactly what RegionPlot[ParametricRegion[{x, Sin[z + t] + Sin[t - z]}, {{x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}}]] is supposed to do in one shot ?

Comment: What do you think the resulting plot will look like, assuming we can use `RegionPlot[ParametricPlot[]]`?

Comment: Not with `ParametricPlot[]` but with `ParametricRegion[]` . As far as I know, since Mathematica 10 we can define a region using `ParametricRegion[]` and then plot it with `RegionPlot[]`. For me, `RegionPlot[ParametricRegion[]]` is supposed to do the job, and I should get the same plot as you. For instance, if I try `RegionPlot[ParametricRegion[{x, Sin[z + t]}, {{x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}}]]`, it works perfectly in one shot. What I do not understand is why when I add a second  term for the ordinate, namely `Sin[t-z]`, it does not work anymore.

Comment: You are right.  That breaks it.  `ParametricRegion[]` can handle it, but then when it is processed by `RegionPlot[]` it cannot handle it.  By the way:  $\sin(z-t)-\sin(z+t)=-2\cos z \sin t.$  It seems that the $z$ parameterization is redundant.  I don't know if this has anything to do with *Mathematica's* inability to plot the sum (or product).